# How make default settings in a library (NuGet package) that can be overridden in a project pulling it in?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-4.0, nuget, app-config

I want to have some default settings in my library that will be distributed as a NuGet package. I want users of this library to be able to override them. How would I do this?

An `app.config` in the Nuget package for the defaults?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Key0" value="0" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then override them in an `app.config` in the project using the library?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Key0" value="45" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

*Note:* This is a .Net standard library that will be used in **both** a .Net Core 2.x *and* .Net Framework 4.7 project.

Comment: Use the .NET Core configuration mechanism in both cases instead of `app.config`.  The `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` package is a .NET Standard 2.0 library which can be used by both frameworks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How would I use this package and let them override the settings? What file would be in the library? And how would I defer to any file in the main project using my library?

Comment: The same way you would for any .NET Core project. You can have multiple configuration providers and newer ones can override the settings added by previous ones. [This article explains how Configuration works in general](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt632279.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The [docs say the same things](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) but refer to ASP.NET Core concepts so they can be a bit confusing at first. The concepts are the same even for console applications though

Comment: You could create a method that accepts an `IConfigurationBuilder` in your library, and configure an in-memory provider (ie a dictionary) with the default settings you want. Users of the library could easily override those by specifying new values for those keys in their configuration.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but would that work in .Net Framework too?

Comment: Yes, the libraries are .NET Standard 2.0 so they run on .NET Framework too. I use them this way for console application tools that need to pull settings from databases as well as settings files.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks. How do you pull from app.config? Xml doesn't seem to be supported by the base libraries.